# Stata Syntax for Hypothesis Tests of Interaction Coefficients

Tags: syntax, stata, interaction

Y is continuous, X is continuous,
and dummy1, dummy2, dummy3 and dummy4 are binary dummies.

I run the following in Stata:

```
reg Y X (dummy1 dummy2 dummy3 dummy4)##c.X
```

which gives me the required output.

I then want to run the hypothesis test that the main effect of dummy1 equals the main effect of dummy2.
I try this using:

```
test dummy1==dummy2
```

But I receive the following error:

> regressor dummy1 not found

What is the correct syntax to perform this hypothesis test?

Also, what is the correct syntax to perform the hypothesis test that the interacted effect with X for dummy1 is the same as for dummy2 (i.e. dummy1#X == dummy2#X)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's good practice to use a toy Stata dataset like cars when asking questions.

The `coefl` option just makes it easier to get the coefficient names. It's not necessary. This would be how I would do it:

```
    sysuse auto, clear
    reg price i.rep78##c.mpg, coefl
    test _b[2.rep78]==_b[3.rep78]
    test _b[2.rep78#c.mpg]==_b[3.rep78#c.mpg]
```

You can also drop the `_b[]`s and the `c.`s:

```
test 2.rep78=3.rep78
test 2.rep78#mpg=3.rep78#mpg
```

If you insist on using your own dummies, then you want something like this:

```
sysuse auto, clear
tab rep78, gen(dummy)
drop dummy5

reg price (dummy?)##c.mpg, coefl
test _b[1.dummy2]==_b[1.dummy3]
test _b[1.dummy2#c.mpg]==_b[1.dummy3#c.mpg]
```

Note that there's no need for a separate mpg terms. The ## notation means both the level and the interaction are in the model.